# Matrix Multiplication, Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have try to create a code that can solve a matrix.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pratical_8 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Taking A Matrix
    System.out.println("Enter number of Rows and Column for first Matrix");
    System.out.print("Enter Rows ");
    int aRLen=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Columns ");
    int aCLen=sc.nextInt();
    int [][] a = new int [aRLen][aCLen];
    System.out.println("Enter Matrix");
    for(int i=0;i<aRLen;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<aCLen;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }//End of j loop
    }//End of I loop

    // Taking B Matrix
    System.out.println("Enter number of Rows and Column for second Matrix");
    System.out.print("Enter Rows ");
    int bRLen=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Columns ");
    int bCLen=sc.nextInt();
    int [][] b = new int [bRLen][bCLen];
    System.out.println("Enter Matrix");
    for(int i=0;i<bRLen;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<bCLen;j++)
        {
            b[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }//End of j loop
    }//End of I loop

    // Creating resulting Matrix
    int [][] r = new int [aRLen][bCLen];

    // Check for Valid input
    if(aCLen!=bRLen)
    {
        System.out.println("Error invalid input");
        System.out.println("Multiplication of this matrix is not possible");

    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<aCLen;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<bRLen;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0; k<bRLen;k++)
                {
                    r[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]; // LINE 57 ERROR
                }//End of k Loop
                System.out.print(r[i][j]+" ");
            }//End of j loop
            System.out.println();
        }//End of I loop
     }//End of if-else
  }//End of main
}//End of class
```

it have an error after sucessfully give an output

Output:-

```
Enter number of Rows and Column for first Matrik
```

Enter Rows 1

Enter Columns 3

Enter Matrix
1
2
3

Enter number of Rows and Column for second Matrix

Enter Rows 3

Enter Columns 1

Enter Matrix
1
2
3

14
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at Pratical_8.main(Pratical_8.java:57)

Process finished with exit code 1

This Error only ocure in non Sysmetrix Matrix

What is the PROBLEM?

Comment: `Index 1 out of bounds for length 1` That's the problem exactly.  You allocated an array of length 1, and then used an index out of bounds. Remember arrays in Java are zero based, so an array of length one has one element at index zero, not one.

Comment: By "solve a matrix" do you mean matrix multiplication?  I'd say those are two very different things.

Comment: Please use sensible titles for your questions.   Silly or meaningless titles will get you downvotes rather than answers.  (If you insist on using silly / unhelpful titles ... my answer to your question is "Yesssss".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the final matrix is of order aRLen x bCLen the last for loops needs to be modified.

```
for(int i=0;i<aRLen;i++)  // Instead of aClen
        {
            for(int j=0;j<bCLen;j++) //Instead of bRlen
            {
                for(int k=0; k<bRLen;k++)
                {
                    r[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]; // LINE 57 ERROR
                }//End of k Loop
                System.out.print(r[i][j]+" ");
            }//End of j loop
            System.out.println();
        }//End of I loop
```

This will work properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).